# Получение данных из переданного массива

Tags: jquery, массивы, php

```
$.ajax({
      url: "modules/mod_yapointer/php/postmaster.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: {
      form: $('#feedback').serialize(), 
      bg: bg_title 
      }
```

Как вытащить в php значения из form? Пробовал по типу `$mod = $_POST['form[ya_mod]'];` но не работает.

***Добавлено:***

Выдача var_dump :

```
array(2) { ["form"]=> string(140) "address=123123&ya_fio=123123&ya_tel=123123123&ya_mark=1&ya_mod=123&ya_years=&from=8&to=9&when=1&ya_date=&ya_text=13123&lng=&lat=&todo=washMe"
```

Попробовал:
$form = $_POST['form'];`
$mod = $form['ya_mod'];

Все так же выдает 'a'

Comment: посмотри что у тебя приходит var_dump($_POST);

Comment: как var_dump загрузить в переменную?

Comment: попробуй так

    ob_start();
    var_dump($_POST);
    $myStr = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$mod = $_POST['form']['ya_mod'];
```

не?

Comment: нет, не работает

Comment: выводит 'a'

Comment: Это если у input name="form[ya_mod]", но если name="ya_mod", то $mod = $_POST['ya_mod'];

Comment: 20 'a' хуже чем ничего

Comment: При таком раскладе надо юзать parse_str($_POST['form']);
В переменной $ya_mod будет содержимое инпута name="ya_mod"

Answer (score 0):

> array(2) { ["form"]=> string(140) "address=123123&ya_fio=123123&ya_tel=123123123&ya_mark=1&ya_mod=123&ya_years=&from=8&to=9&when=1&ya_date=&ya_text=13123&lng=&lat=&todo=washMe"

Судя по выводу, у вас в form помещается всё одной строкой, т.е. доставать параметры надо из строки (или менять какаие-то настройки). Накидал небольшой код, который разбивает набор параметров:

```
    $form = $_POST['form'];
    $ar = explode('&', $form);
    $ya_mod_value = "";
    foreach ($ar as $row)
    {
        $kv = explode('=', $row, 2);
        if (count($kv) == 2 && $kv[0] == 'ya_mod')
        {
            $ya_mod_value = $kv[1];
        }
    }
    echo $ya_mod_value;
```

**Добавлено:**

и еще небольшой код, который перекидывает все в массив `$form_arr`

```
    $form = $_POST['form'];
    $ar = explode('&', $form);
    $form_arr = array();
    foreach ($ar as $row)
    {
        $kv = explode('=', $row, 2);
        if (count($kv) == 2)
        {
            $form_arr[$kv[0]] = $kv[1];
        }
    }
    print_r($form_arr);
    echo $form_arr['ya_mod'];
```

или использовать стандартную функцию:

```
parse_str($_POST['form'], $form_arr);
print_r($form_arr);
echo $form_arr['ya_mod'];
```

Comment: Никаких explode() не нужно. Для таких целей есть функция [parse_str()](http://ua2.php.net/manual/ru/function.parse-str.php)

Answer (score -2):

а если так? `$mod = $_POST['ya_mod'];`

и вообще то код формы дай

Comment: так точно не работает

Comment: код формы постить бесмысленно, там 20 инпутов + многострочные селекты. Но код этой строчки приведу

<div><p class="ya_label">Модель авто</p><input type="text" name="ya_mod" value="" id="ya5"/></div>

Comment: Если что .serialize()это массив в котором лежат имена и значения полей формы по типу:
имя инпута: его значение,
имя инпута: его значение,